# How to specify the type of pandas series elements in type hints?

Tags: python, pandas, series, type-hinting

My function returns a pandas series, where all elements have a specific type (say `str`). The following MWE should give an impression:

```
import pandas as pd 
def f() -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series(['a', 'b'])
```

Within the type hints I want to make clear, that `f()[0]` will always be of type `str` (compared for example to a function that would return`pd.Series([0, 1])`). I did this:

```
def f() -> pd.Series[str]:
```

But

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

So, how to specify the type of pandas series elements in type hints?. Any ideas?

Comment: `pd.Series(dtype=str)` allows you to specify the data type of a series' elements. My guess is that this also works for type hints.

Comment: `pd.Series(dtype=str)` does not work for type hints.

Comment: Is there an "str" type in pandas ? Not sure, according to https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html (but maybe deprecated ?)

Comment: @ItamarMushkin: just out of couriosity, why do you think `pd.Series(dtype=str)` does not work for type hints? My 3.7 interpretor at least accepts it syntactically.

Comment: @jottbe -- it's not a valid PEP 484 type. So while there's nothing stopping you from writing such a type hint, it would end up causing any tooling designed to analyze PEP 484 type hints to choke. (Static type checkers, linters, autocompletion tools...). Losing access to those tools would greatly diminish the usefulness of type hints to the point where you're probably better off not using them at all.

Comment: @Michael0x2a: ok I see. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Also, it didn't run for me on 3.6.1 (Jupyter notebook if that matters)

Answer (score 11):

you can use `pandera` for type-hinting and validating dataframes and series: https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/schema_models.html#schema-models

so in this case:

```
from pandera.typing import Series
import pandas as pd 

def f() -> Series[str]:
    return pd.Series(['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: mypy still complains: error: Incompatible return value type (got "pandas.core.series.Series[str]", expected "pandera.typing.pandas.Series[str]")

Comment: You probably need to enable the `pandera.mypy` plugin. See [here](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mypy_integration.html)

Comment: I did enable the plugin. Maybe it's because I also use pydantic.mypy. With pydantic, pandera and mypy somehow two are ok and the third one is complaining, no matter how you configure it. MyPy complains about valid slices, thinks selecting a MultiIndex df results in a scalar etc. The closest I got was to type functions with comments `# type: (pd.Series[float], pd.Series[float]) -> pd.DataFrame` but that did not really validate the type. And I ended up with hundreds of `# type: ignore`. I gave up on mypy with pandas.

Answer (score 10):

For python 3.8 try:

```py
def f() -> "pd.Series[str]":
    pass
```

or:

```py
f_return_type = "pd.Series[str]"
def f() -> f_return_type:
    pass
```

or `# type: pd.Series[str]` for variables

Comment: This works, but where can I find this type of annotations (inside stringns) in the python docs? I didn't find them in pep. and in the docs of typing there is only two example with no info about them: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: This does NOT work. `def f() -> "pd.Series[float]":
    return pd.Series(["a", "b"], dtype=str)` is happily validated as correctly typed.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make clear that f()[0] will always be of type `str` (compared to a function that would return pd.Series([0, 1]))

This may be a great use-case to annotate the type based on how the value will be used, instead of what it is.  ("has method" vs "is type" annotation).

In this case, the slice behavior is covered by the `Sequence` type.

```py
from typing import Sequence
import pandas as pd

def returns_str_sequence() -> Sequence[str]:
    return pd.Series(['a', 'b'])

def uses_str_sequence(data: Sequence[str]):
    for _ in data:
        pass  # Iterable behavior also covered
    return data[0]  # slice works via __getitem__
```

For a fuller list of possible types you can use, feel free to review this [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) for the `collections.abc` module.

This may have a side benefit of de-coupling your code from 3rd party code/types as well, as your functions will be defined to handle more abstract types.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Python's type hinting does not support this out of the shelf. Nonetheless, you can always make use of `dataenforce` library ([link](https://github.com/CedricFR/dataenforce)) to add hints or even enforce validation.

Comment: Can you provide how this actually would be done for ´pd.Series´? Is this done using `DatasetMeta` (https://github.com/CedricFR/dataenforce/blob/master/dataenforce/__init__.py)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work currently and will not until [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) is finalized.

To get it to work

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

The PEPs around typing continue to evolve, as does Python... See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/__future__.html#id1) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize `typing.TypeVar` to accomplish this:

```
from typing import (
    TypeVar
)

SeriesString = TypeVar('pandas.core.series.Series(str)')
def f() -> SeriesString:
```

Comment: Isn't the string there just a _name_ (conventionally the same as the variable it's assigned to)?

Comment: This is absolutely not a valid type annotation, nor is it the correct use of `TypeVar`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe not *just* conventionally, it has to be for it to follow PEP 484

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga insofar as [that says](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics) _"The argument to `TypeVar()` must be a string equal to the variable name to which it is assigned"_, yes. But I don't think anything actually _breaks_ if it's not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it breaks static type checkers

Answer (score -4):

You can specify using dtype parameter

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(['a', 'b'], dtype='str')
```

for more information [click here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html)

Comment: HI Mohan, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the solution does not work, since `data` is an unresolved reference, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Qaswed the Data is the data you want add it to the series.. for your problem below code will work. The data type will show as object. str data type is also object type

`import pandas as pd
pd.Series(['a', 'b'], dtype='str')`