# Type hints for a pandas DataFrame with mixed dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, type-hinting

I've been looking for robust type hints for a pandas DataFrame, but cannot seem to find anything useful. This question barely scratches the surface [Pythonic type hints with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890844/pythonic-type-hints-with-pandas)

Normally if I want to hint the type of a function, that has a DataFrame as an input argument I would do:

```
import pandas as pd 
def func(arg: pd.DataFrame) -> int: 
     return 1
```

What I cannot seem to find is how do I type hint a DataFrame with **mixed dtypes**. The DataFrame constructor supports only type definition of the complete DataFrame. So to my knowledge changes in the dtypes can only occur afterwards with the `pd.DataFrame().astype(dtypes={})` function.

This here works, but doesn't seem very pythonic to me

```
import datetime
def func(arg: pd.DataFrame(columns=['integer', 'date']).astype(dtype={'integer': int, 'date': datetime.date})) -> int:
    return 1
```

I came across this package: https://pypi.org/project/dataenforce/ with examples such as this one:

```
def process_data(data: Dataset["id": int, "name": object, "latitude": float, "longitude": float])
  pass
```

This looks somewhat promising, but sadly the project is old and buggy.

As a data scientist, building a machine learning application with long ETL processes I believe that type hints are important.

What do you use and does anybody type hint their dataframes in pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify the type of pandas series elements in type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854936/how-to-specify-the-type-of-pandas-series-elements-in-type-hints)

Comment: Partly - I found this package too, but whenever I try to use it, I get this error `__init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments`

Unfortunately I am not familiar with Meta Classes and cannot solve this bug on my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have now found the pandera library that seems very promising:

https://github.com/pandera-dev/pandera

It allows users to create schemas and use those schemas to create verbose checks. From their docs:

https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/schema_models.html

```
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import Index, DataFrame, Series


class InputSchema(pa.SchemaModel):
    year: Series[int] = pa.Field(gt=2000, coerce=True)
    month: Series[int] = pa.Field(ge=1, le=12, coerce=True)
    day: Series[int] = pa.Field(ge=0, le=365, coerce=True)

class OutputSchema(InputSchema):
    revenue: Series[float]

@pa.check_types
def transform(df: DataFrame[InputSchema]) -> DataFrame[OutputSchema]:
    return df.assign(revenue=100.0)


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "year": ["2001", "2002", "2003"],
    "month": ["3", "6", "12"],
    "day": ["200", "156", "365"],
})

transform(df)

invalid_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "year": ["2001", "2002", "1999"],
    "month": ["3", "6", "12"],
    "day": ["200", "156", "365"],
})
transform(invalid_df)
```

Also a note from them:

> Due to current limitations in the pandas library (see discussion here), pandera annotations are only used for run-time validation and cannot be leveraged by static-type checkers like mypy. See the discussion here for more details.

But still, even though there is no static-type checking I think that this is going in a very good direction.

Comment: new in 0.8.0: Pandera integrates with mypy to provide static type-linting of dataframes, relying on pandas-stubs for typing information.

Answer (score 1):

While not Pandas, [StaticFrame](https://github.com/static-frame/static-frame) (an alternative DataFrame library built on an immutable data model, of which I am an author) permits full type-hinting of a DataFrame, including mixed columnar types. You can easily convert between StaticFrame and Pandas if needed.

For example, to type hint the `func`, above, we could define `arg` as a StaticFrame `sf.Frame` that has any type of index, string column labels (given as `sf.Index[np.str_]`), and two columns of data values specified as `np.int64` and `np.object_` arrays (the last one holding `datetime.date` objects).

```py
from typing import Any
import numpy as np
import static_frame as sf

def func(arg: sf.Frame[Any, sf.Index[np.str_], np.int64, np.object_]) -> int:
    return 1
```

More examples can be seen [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/type-hinting-dataframes-for-static-analysis-and-runtime-validation-3dedd2df481d).