# Type hinting Pandas DataFrame content and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a function that returns a Pandas `DataFrame` object. I would like to have some kind of a type hinting what columns this `DataFrame` contains, outside mere specification in the documentation, as I feel this will make it much easier for the end user to read the data.

Is there a way to type hint `DataFrame` content that different tools like Visual Studio Code and PyCharm would support, when editing Python files and when editing Jupyter Notebooks?

An example function:

```py
def generate_data(bunch, of, inputs) -> pd.DataFrame:
      """Massages the input to a nice and easy DataFrame.

      :return:
           DataFrame with columns a(int), b(float), c(string), d(us dollars as float)
      """
```

Comment: Use hinterland extension: https://towardsdatascience.com/12-jupyter-notebook-extensions-that-will-make-your-life-easier-e0aae0bd181

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most powerful project for strong typing of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) `DataFrame` as of now (Apr 2023) is [pandera](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera). Unfortunately, what it offers is quite limited and far from what we might have wanted.

Here is an example of how you can use `pandera` in your case<sup>†</sup>:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import DataFrame

class MySchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    a: int
    b: float
    c: str = pa.Field(nullable=True)  # For example, allow None values
    d: float    # US dollars

class OtherSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    year: int = pa.Field(ge=1900, le=2050)


def generate_data() -> DataFrame[MySchema]:
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "a": [1, 2, 3],
        "b": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0],
        "c": ["A", "B", "C"],
        "d": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
    })

    # Runtime verification here, throws on schema mismatch
    strongly_typed_df = DataFrame[MySchema](df)
    return strongly_typed_df

def transform(input: DataFrame[MySchema]) -> DataFrame[OtherSchema]:
    # This demonstrates that you can use strongly
    # typed column names from the schema
    df = input.filter(items=[MySchema.a]).rename(
            columns={MySchema.a: OtherSchema.year}
    )

    return DataFrame[OtherSchema](df) # This will throw on range validation!


df1 = generate_data()
df2 = transform(df1)
transform(df2)   # mypy prints error here - incompatible type!
```

You can see `mypy` producing static type check error on the last line:

[image]

### Discussion of advantages and limitations

With pandera we get –

1. Clear and readable (`dataclass` style) `DataFrame` schema definitions and ability to use them as type hints.
2. Run-time schema verification. Schema can define even more constraints than just types (see `year` in the example below and `pandera` docs for more).
3. [Experimental](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mypy_integration.html#mypy-integration) support for static type checking by [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org/).

What we still miss –

1. Full static type checking for column level verification.
2. Any IDE support for column name auto-completion.
3. Inline syntax for schema declaration, we have to explicitly define each schema as separate class before using it.

### More examples

Pandera docs - https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataframe_models.html

Similar question - [Type hints for a pandas DataFrame with mixed dtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386477/type-hints-for-a-pandas-dataframe-with-mixed-dtypes)

### Other typing projects

[pandas-stubs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs) is an active project providing type declarations for the pandas public API which is richer than type stubs included in pandas itself. But it doesn't provide any facilities for column level schemas.

There are quite a few outdated libraries related to this and pandas typing in general - [dataenforce](https://github.com/CedricFR/dataenforce), [data-science-types](https://github.com/wearepal/data-science-types), [python-type-stubs](https://github.com/microsoft/python-type-stubs)

<sub>† `pandera` provides two different APIs that seem to be equally powerful - object-based API and class-based API. I demonstrate the later here.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have noted, there appears no way to answer the question using Pandas alone. While Pandera is one third-party answer, [StaticFrame](https://github.com/static-frame/static-frame) (of which I am an author) is another. StaticFrame is an alternative DataFrame library built on an immutable data model; you can define interfaces in StaticFrame and easily convert to Pandas as needed.

To fully type hint the column label and columnar value types of the returned DataFrame in the example above, you can do the following with StaticFrame:

```py
from typing import Any
import numpy as np
import static_frame as sf

def generate_data(bunch, of, inputs) -> sf.Frame[
        Any,                # the type of the index labels
        sf.Index[np.str_],  # the type of the column labels
        np.int64,           # the type of the first column
        np.float64,         # the type of the second column
        np.str_,            # the type of the third column
        np.float64,           # the type of the fourth column
        ]:
    """Massages the input to a nice and easy DataFrame.

    :return:
        DataFrame with columns a(int), b(float), c(string), d(us dollars as float)
    """
    ...
```

This specification is statically checkable with Pyright now (and MyPy soon, assuming full support for `TypeVarTuple` in the future). This specification can also be checked at run-time with StaticFrame's `CallGuard.check` decorator.

The remaining details in the original doc string are (in my interpretation) not typing specifications. StaticFrame, however, supports other run-time checks using `CallGuard.check` and `Annotated` generics in your type hints. Using StaticFrame's `Require.LabelsOrder` validator with the columns label type, you can specify label values as well as arbitrary functional checks.

```py
from typing import Any, Annotated
import numpy as np
import static_frame as sf

@sf.CallGuard.check
def generate_data(bunch, of, inputs) -> sf.Frame[
        Any,                # the type of the index labels
        Annotated[
                sf.Index[np.str_],  # the type of the column labels
                sf.Require.LabelsOrder('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
                ]
        np.int64,           # the type of the first column
        np.float64,         # the type of the second column
        np.str_,            # the type of the third column
        np.float64,           # the type of the fourth column
        ]:
    """Massages the input to a nice and easy DataFrame.

    :return:
        DataFrame with columns a(int), b(float), c(string), d(us dollars as float)
    """
    ...
```

Additional examples can be seen in this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/type-hinting-dataframes-for-static-analysis-and-runtime-validation-3dedd2df481d) or in the StaticFrame [docs](https://static-frame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/ftyping.html).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to do this with just core Python and pandas.

I would recommend using [pandera](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). It has a broader scope, but type checking dataframe column types is one of its capabilities.

pandera can also be used [in conjunction](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pydantic_integration.html) with [pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/), for which in turn dedicated [VS Code (via Pylance)](https://docs.pydantic.dev/visual_studio_code/) and [Pycharm](https://docs.pydantic.dev/pycharm_plugin/) plugins are available.

Comment: For a 500 point bounty I think it would be worth supplying examples that can satisfy the function OP has declared.

Answer (score 1):

Arne is right, Python's type-hinting does not have any native out-of-the-box support for specifying col types in a Pandas DataFrame.

You can perhaps use comments with custom types

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import pandas as pd

class MyDataFrame(NamedTuple):
    a: int
    b: float
    c: str
    d: float  # US dollars as float

def generate_data(bunch, of, inputs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Massages the input to a nice and easy DataFrame.

    :return:
        DataFrame with columns a(int), b(float), c(string), d(us dollars as float)
    """
    # Your implementation here
    pass
```

This is a sample approach you could take. It defines a custom NamedTuple called MyDataFrame. Of course, it's not strictly type-hinting the DataFrame, and IDE and type-checking tools wont enforce it, but it provides a hint to the user about the expected struct of the output DataFrame.

An alternative approach you could take is using a custom type alias and docstring

```
from typing import Any, Dict
import pandas as pd

# Define a type alias for better documentation
DataFrameWithColumns = pd.DataFrame

def generate_data(bunch: Any, of: Any, inputs: Any) -> DataFrameWithColumns:
    """
    Massages the input to a nice and easy DataFrame.

    :param bunch: Description of the input parameter 'bunch'
    :param of: Description of the input parameter 'of'
    :param inputs: Description of the input parameter 'inputs'

    :return: DataFrame with columns:
        a (int): Description of column 'a'
        b (float): Description of column 'b'
        c (str): Description of column 'c'
        d (float): US dollars as float, description of column 'd'
    """
    # Your implementation here
    pass
```

Here, you could define a custom type alias for pd.DataFrame to represent the expectec output DataFrame, which could be helpful to end-users

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to fully understand what you expect. Isn't `df.info()` sufficient to help users?

```
>>> df.info()
<class '__main__.MyDataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   a       3 non-null      int64  
 1   b       3 non-null      float64
 2   c       3 non-null      object 
 3   d       3 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 224.0+ bytes
```

If not, you can [subclassing `DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) and override methods like `info` and `__repr__`. You can store additional informations in `attrs` dictionary and use it in these methods. Here an example:

```
class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    
    def info(self):
        super().info()
        s = '\nMore information as footer:\n'
        s += self.attrs.get('more_info')
        print(s)

    def __repr__(self):
        s = 'More information as header:\n'
        s += f"{self.attrs.get('more_info')}\n\n"
        s += super().__repr__()
        return s
        
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDataFrame

def generate_data(bunch, of, inputs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = MyDataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': [1.0, 1.1, 1.2],
                      'c': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'd': [0.99, 2.49, 3.99]})
    df.attrs = {
        'more_info': 'Additional information here'
    }
    return df

df = generate_data('nothing', 'to', 'do')
```

Usage:

```
>>> df
More information as header:  # <- HERE
Additional information here  # <- HERE

   a    b  c     d
0  0  1.0  A  0.99
1  1  1.1  B  2.49
2  2  1.2  C  3.99
```

```
>>> df.info()
<class '__main__.MyDataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   a       3 non-null      int64  
 1   b       3 non-null      float64
 2   c       3 non-null      object 
 3   d       3 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 224.0+ bytes

More information as footer:  # <- HERE
Additional information here  # <- HERE
```

```
>>> df[['a', 'b']]
More information as header:
Additional information here

   a    b
0  0  1.0
1  1  1.1
2  2  1.2
```

I just used a simple string but you can have a more complex `attrs` structure and a special function to display this dict (check if columns exist and avoid display useless information). I hope this helps.

Comment: Static analysers like PyCharm, Pylanche (used in Visual Studio Code) and MyPy do not have visibility to `df.info()` and thus cannot help the DataFrame user about the correctness of the code.

Comment: You can also override __repr__?