# How do you type hint the contents of a pandas series that is being passed into a function?

Tags: pandas, types, type-hinting, python-typing

I have two functions that take in a `pd.Series` argument

```
def function_1(ages:pd.Series)->float:
    ...
```

and

```
def function_2(names:pd.Series)->int:
    ...
```

However, for `function_1` the input is a `pd.Series` of integers, and for `function_2` it's a `pd.Series` of strings.

I'd like to be able to write:

```
def function_1(ages:pd.Series[int])->float:
    ...

def function_2(names:pd.Series[str])->int:
    ...
```

However this gives the error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Note: for now I'm doing

```
def function_1(ages:'pd.Series[int]')->float:
    ...

def function_2(names:'pd.Series[str]')->int:
    ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify the type of pandas series elements in type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854936/how-to-specify-the-type-of-pandas-series-elements-in-type-hints)