# How to specify variable type of a pandas Series (string or TypeVar)?

Tags: python, pandas, python-typing

I want to use type hinting for something like:

```
def fo() -> pd.Series[np.float64]:
   return pd.Series(np.float64[0])
```

This won't work.

From this answer: [How to specify the type of pandas series elements in type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854936/how-to-specify-the-type-of-pandas-series-elements-in-type-hints)

I understand I can use either:

```
def fo() -> "pd.Series[np.float64]":
   return pd.Series(np.float64[0])
```

Or:

```
from typing import (
    TypeVar
)

SeriesFloat64 = TypeVar('pd.Series[np.float64]')
def fo() -> SeriesFloat64:
   return pd.Series(np.float64[0])
```

Why should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: I think that would be a misuse of a `TypeVar` and not give the checker any information - the first argument is just a _name_: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics, https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar.

Comment: I assume you meant to return a `pd.Series(np.float64(0))`, not with the square brackets around the `0`, to instantiate a float with the value zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Both "solutions" you referenced are wrong

I'll start with the second one:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

SeriesFloat64 = TypeVar('pd.Series[np.float64]')

def fo() -> SeriesFloat64:
    return pd.Series(np.float64(0))
```

Is this type variable *technically* a valid annotation? Yes. Does it specify the generic `pd.Series`? No.

First of all, as @jonrsharpe pointed out, this breaks the convention of initializing your [type variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) with a `name` argument that corresponds to the actual name of the variable. More importantly, neither `bound` nor `constraints` have been specified, meaning you might as well have just written this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

T = TypeVar("T")  # which is the same as `TypeVar("T", bound=typing.Any)`

def fo() -> T:
    return pd.Series(np.float64(0))
```

This would at least fix the name issue, but it would not **specify** anything about the return type of `fo()`. In fact, `mypy` will correctly point out the following:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Series[Any]", expected "T")  [return-value]
```

Which already gives a hint about what we can and cannot do regarding specification of `pd.Series` and this leads us to the second "solution":

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

def fo() -> "pd.Series[np.float64]":
    return pd.Series(np.float64(0))
```

This is equivalent, by the way: (no quotes needed)

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

def fo() -> pd.Series[np.float64]:
    return pd.Series(np.float64(0))
```

This is wrong because the type parameter for the generic `Series` does not accept `np.float64`. Again, `mypy` points this out:

```
error: Value of type variable "S1" of "Series" cannot be "floating"  [type-var]
```

If we check out the `pandas-stubs` source for [`core.series.Series`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/blob/v1.4.4.220919/pandas-stubs/core/series.pyi#L163) (as of today), we see that `Series` inherits from `typing.Generic[S1]`. And when we go to the definition of [`_typing.S1`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/blob/v1.4.4.220919/pandas-stubs/_typing.pyi#L144), we can see the constraints on that type variable. And a numpy float is not among them, but we *do* find the built-in `float`. What does that mean?

Well, we know that `np.float64` does inherit from the regular `float`, **but it also inherits from `np.floating`**, and that is the issue. As mentioned in [this section of PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound), as opposed to an upper bound

> type constraints cause the inferred type to be *exactly* one of the constraint types[.]

This means that you are *not* allowed to use `np.float64` in place of the aforementioned `S1` to specify a `Series` type.

---

### A better way

The "most correct" way to type hint that function, in my opinion, is to do this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

def fo() -> pd.Series[float]:
    return pd.Series(np.float64(0))
```

This makes correct use of the `Series` generic providing a type variable that is both in line with the defined type constraints **and** indicates an element type for the series returned by the function that as close as you can get to the actual type since `np.float64` *does* inherit from `float`.

It also passed the strict `mypy` check.

---

### Adding useful information

One caveat of this is that you lose the information that the series *actually* contains 64-bit floats. If you want that because you want the signature/documentation for the function to reflect that nuance, you can simply set up a custom type alias:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

float64 = float

def fo() -> pd.Series[float64]:
    return pd.Series(np.float64(0))
```

Now calling `help(fo)` gives this:

```
...
fo() -> 'pd.Series[float64]'
```

But it is important to note that this is just for *your* benefit and does absolutely nothing for the static type checker.

---

### Limitations of `pd.Series` types

Another thing worth mentioning is that as of today, there are no useful annotations on many of the methods of a `pd.Series` that return a single element, such as the [`__getitem__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.0/pandas/core/series.py#L967) method for access via the square brackets `[]`. Say I do this:

```py
...
series = fo()
x = series[0]
print(x, type(x))
y = int(x)
```

The output is `0.0 <class 'numpy.float64'>`, but type checkers have **no clue** that `x` is a `np.float64` or any `float` at all for that matter. (In fact, my PyCharm complains at `y = int(x)` because it thinks `x` is a timestamp for whatever reason.)

This is just to illustrate that as of now, you may not get any useful auto-suggestions when dealing with `pd.Series`, even if you annotate your types more or less correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But `pd.Series[str]` doesn't parse in Python 3.10, at least for a function argument type:

`E   TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @rjurney it does *parse* (if it didn't, it would raise a `SyntaxError` not a `TypeError`). The pandas data types do not support generic type annotations (who knows if they ever will), that's why this answer explained that you need to use either *strings* or to use `from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you can just use "pd.Series(str)" and it works ok. Your answer is fantastic, but that bit didn't work for me without parenthesis.

Comment: @rjurney `pd.Series(str)` **is not a valid type annotation**. Anyway, this isn't my answer

Comment: @rjurney I don't know what you mean by "it works". If you mean, "it doesn't throw an error", then that's true, but neither does, say, "banana"

Comment: @rjurney Your answer below and your use of `TypeVar` indicate that you are very confused about the basics of type annotations and the typing constructs provided in Python. I would suggest you read through [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483) (theory) and [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484) (implementations). I think I explained well enough what limitations we face with the Pandas classes and how we can work around that and 
juanpa.arrivillaga even addressed what you misunderstood. If you have further questions, feel free to post them and link them in a comment here.