# How does strings typehints work in the output of a function?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy, hint

Recently I had a typehint problem for which the only solution I found is to make the typehint as a string:

```
import pandas as pd
def fun() -> pd.Series[str]: # returns an ERROR
    return pd.Series(['hola'])

def fun() -> "pd.Series[str]": # Does work and the IDE gets that whatever inside the series is a str
    return pd.Series(['hola'])
```

The solution was here:
[How to specify the type of pandas series elements in type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854936/how-to-specify-the-type-of-pandas-series-elements-in-type-hints)

However I didn't find any useful documentation not in pep nor in the python docs explaining this form of typehints as a string and why the first solution doesn't work but the second does.

In the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) they appear twice (typing.self, typing.TypeVarTuple chapters), but it is not explained how are they evaluated differently. Anyone knows why is like that? or where is this documented in the docs / pep? Or how is this feature called?

Comment: What exactly is the error being returned…?

Comment: And, well, the difference is that the `[]` notation needs to actually be supported by the class when written as `pd.Series[str]`; if it doesn't explicitly support that, then that's an error, the same as any other invalid operation on an object. But when written as string, it's just a meaningless string, that your IDE and/or mypy impart some meaning on.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, at least not with the ones suggested, I'm not asking how make typehints in python now in pandas.

Comment: "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable", is the error, which probably means your explanation @deceze is right but not very complete nor documented. I thought typehints were ignored at runtime, so it seems they aren't.

Comment: The types are not *checked*, no. The type hints still need to be *valid expressions* though. If `pd.Series[str]` raises an error, then it'll do that, because it needs to be evaluated.

Comment: @deceze ok that makes sense, but that should be documented somewhere, at least in mypy, do you really think this question is duplicated?

Comment: [*"Parameters may have an annotation of the form “: expression” following the parameter name. .. Functions may have “return” annotation of the form “-> expression” after the parameter list. __These annotations can be any valid Python expression.__"*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

Comment: @deceze ok, that together with the second comment looks more like a proper answer, but do you really think this question is duplicated?

Comment: If you maybe rephrased it to something like “why does this arbitrary type hint raise this error (error details here), I thought they aren’t being checked?”, it might be worth reopening.